# Apache virtual subdomains

Tags: apache, xampp, subdomain

I'm trying to create virtual subdomains but apache fails to start after I edit the httpd-vhosts.conf and there are no errors in the error log.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerAlias *.localhost
  UseCanonicalName Off    
  VirtualDocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I'm running apache via xampp on windows.

Comment: for those not having xampp but knowing apache, can you drop a word about the original contents of httpd-vhosts.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struggled with the same problem a while ago. You have to enable the vhost_alias module.

In **apache/conf/httpd.conf** find this line and uncomment it

```
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what I am writing is not a solution. But try using [Ampps](http://www.ampps.com). It gives an interface to create subdomains which is good for users who don't know much about Apache configurations.